# public key not valid php rsa

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa, public-key

I tried this simple code :

```
<?php

$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public("public.pem");
$plaintext = "String to encrypt";

openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $publicKey);

echo $encrypted;   //encrypted string

?>
```

but I get this error message.

> Warning: openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key in C:\xampp\htdocs\encrypt\encrypt_rsa.php on line 6

Comment: I guess that `public.pem` is already a public key thus no need to extract it using `openssl_pkey_get_public("public.pem")` - just use it like `openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, 'public.pem');`.

Comment: still the same problem :(

Comment: Can you post the contents of `public.pem` in your question?

Comment: What is the header for your `pem` file? it could be that it is in the wrong format